# Regex to match specific word

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

**C#**

```
        string myString = @"'Key:Apple
                            'Key:Apple123";
        string pattern = "('Key:Apple)|('Key: Apple)";
        int count = Regex.Matches(myString, pattern).Count;
        Console.WriteLine(count); //displaying count as 2
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I am searching for only Apple (not Apple123), but still the count I am getting as 2. How to only search for specific word "Apple" and then, show the count as 1?

I have tried the following approach:

```
            string myString = @"'Key:Apple
                                'Key:Apple123";
            string pattern = "(\\b'Key:Apple\\b)|(\\b'Key: Apple\\b)";
            int count = Regex.Matches(myString, pattern).Count;
            Console.WriteLine(count); //displaying count as 0
            Console.ReadLine();
```

By using the above approach, we are getting the count as zero.

Please advice. Thanks!

Comment: Try `'Key: ?Apple\b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your pattern with:

```
string pattern = @"(Key:\bApple\b)|(Key: \bApple\b)";
```

The `\b` checks the word boundaries and is able to evaluate count as 1 with your example.

You can read more about it [here.](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: You can further simplify this pattern by making the whitespace after `Key` optional with `?`: `string pattern = @"('Key: ?Apple\b)"`

Comment: Good point @derpirscher!

Comment: Thanks!! The issue has been resolved!

Comment: Best of luck with your projects!